# Fast search on large data tables on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, full-text-search

I face the following problem. I have two large tables with about 80.000 records each and  I want to use them on Windows Phone Application. An Sqlite3 based solution is very slow. All other existing database solutions for Windows Phone did not support full text searching.

Any better solution? A similar application on iPhone output search results in milliseconds.

Comment: this does not really fit the stack overflow format.  This site is for specific questions about specific problems, in which you can provide a quantifiable example of the issue at hand.  That being said, doesn't matter what db you use, you're going to have performance issues with an 80k record table on a phone, and outside of optimizing your dataset through indexing and normalization, there's not going to be much you can do about it. perhaps you should consider hosting your dataset on the internet and connecting to it from the phone to perform your queries.

Comment: This is a very specific and interest problem for stack overflow format because your comment is wrong! And it is wrong because the same application using LARGER tables on iPhone output results in milliseconds without internet hosting! It is obvious that the Windows Phone computational power is enough ....if you now what to do. This knowledge is that I am looking for. Of course iPhone is using C++ and WP C# and probably this limitation does not permit a solution.

Comment: @ Chris Drappier If you have any doubt I can send you the iPhone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there is no full text search (FTS) support on SQL Compact (Windows Phone supported database engine).

I've been waiting on [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for a while, hopping they will release a Silverlight compatible version (there have been some requests for it), thus allowing us to make a FTS engine for our SQL Compact databases.

Comment: Yes Lucene.net is probably a solution with SQL Compact. However until now I am stack with SQlite3.